# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(3n)! + 4^{(n+1)}}{(3n+1)!}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

does the serie $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(3n)! + 4^{(n+1)}}{(3n+1)!}$ converge or diverge?

I tried this : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(3n)! + 4^{(n+1)}}{(3n+1)!}=  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  [\frac{3n!}{(3n+1)!}  +  \frac{4^{n+1}}{(3n+1)!} ] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3n+1)} +  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4^{n+1}}{(3n+1)!} $ but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3n+1)}$ is not convergent , some help please?

Comment: You have already answered your own question!

Comment: then the serie diverge ?

Comment: Yes. In your last line you have a sum of two positive series one of which diverge. Conclusion follows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac{(3n)! + 4^{(n+1)}}{(3n+1)!}>\frac{(3n)!}{(3n+1)!}=\frac{1}{3n+1}\ .$$

Comment: but the $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3n + 1}$ diverges

Comment: Yes exactly, and this immediately gives the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using what you've shown,

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(3n)! + 4^{n + 1}}{(3n + 1)!} \ge \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3(n + 1)}$$

since $4^{n + 1} > 0$ for all $n$. Now compare.

Comment: $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^{n + 1}}$ this converge

Comment: I fixed it; I meant to use the estimate you already made in your question.